# Queue implementation in C#

Tags: c#, queue

I'm dealing with a hardware resource that can only handle 1 command at a time.  I'm going to exposing some of it's API functions via a web interface, so obviously there's a good chance more than 1 command will get sent at a time.  I have decided that queuing these commands when they're submitted is the best way to ensure serial processing.

I'm planning on implementing the queue in a static class.  The web app code-behind will add a command by calling a method corresponding to the command they want.  I want the calling method to wait until it gets the output of its command, so no async magic is required.

1. Am I doing this right?  Is there a better way?
2. How do I start implementing the queue in C# (I usually work with Java)?  I assume I'll need some sort Event to signal a job has been added, and a Handler to initiate processing of the queue...

I'm using .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Can you modify your question to clarify which version of .NET you're using?  That will determine whether you can use a ConcurrentQueue(4.0+) or Queue(2.0+).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) class for your implementation and have a dedicated thread to process items in the queue.

For the waiting part you can use an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx), producers pass the event instance to the singleton class along with the request, then calls `WaitOne()` which blocks until the processor has signaled processing is completed by calling `Set()`.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a good approach **EXCEPT**: Use the [Generic Queue collections class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) **Do not** write your own! You would be reinventing a well-built wheel.